# On Cloudflare, pointing homepage to one host and the rest of the website to another

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I'm managing my domain with Cloudflare.

Is it possible, and if so how, to point only the homepage (frontpage) to one host and the rest of the application to another?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Cloudflare works by receiving all your traffic when you setup your DNS's to theirs, meaning all the traffic passes through their servers and no separation is made between the homepage and the rest of the application.

To load only certain parts of your site through Cloudflare and others don't, what you can do is create some type of subdomain and point that to Clouflare. This can be useful if you want to have asynchronous sources to do, for example, something like images.yourwebsite.com that can act like a simple CDN.

Also, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I would like to put the homepage (the static html/css files for it) on a easily accessible server such that other people on my team can change the content. The rest of the application is deployed on Heroku it would a hassle for them to learn the versioning system etc.

Comment: Yes, in that case is possible. Create a subdomain like static.yoursite.com and fit everything you want inside. The problem is that now on Heroku deployment you'll have to point to that subdomain in order to load the files.

Comment: Thanks! I *think* I understood what you mean, I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: by using the CNAME feature on Cloudflare you should be able to do it, check here-> https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup- Meanwhile if my answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: I'd love to accept you answer but it is a bit contradictive (your first sentence vs the solution)..

Comment: My first sentence actually replies to your question: It's not possible to redirect only the homepage to Cloudflare. The solution ended up being something different than the original question because you revealed other details (such as Heroku deployment) in the comments. What you want is the asynchronous loading of assets, which I pointed in it. For what is worth, my answer is correct.